# How express SQL query using Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, orm

I have an example application of the shop.

Full application code is available at https://github.com/dry-python/tutorials/tree/master/django

In this example, User can buy a subscription for different categories of
the content.

The user can subscribe for one day, one month or one year.

Each period has its own price.

Price can change in time, so Price model stores not the actual prices
but the whole Price history.

The Price with the most recent from_date value is the actual one.

This is the Price model.

```
class Price(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="prices", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    from_date = models.DateField()

    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    period = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to select the cheapest (from actual) price for each category.

I can express this with following SQL query.

```
SELECT "category_id",
       MIN("cost")
  FROM "example_price"
 WHERE "id" IN (
   SELECT "id"
     FROM "example_price"
    WHERE "category_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
    GROUP BY "category_id", "period"
   HAVING "from_date" = MAX("from_date")
 )
 GROUP BY "category_id"
```

How I can express it with Django ORM?

Regards, Artem.

Comment: Without attempting to translate that query myself and screwing up the details, I'm going to suggest you review [Django's aggregation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/). That should provide the direction you need.

Comment: I tried all combinations of `values`, `annotate` and `filter`. I don't understand how to get different fields in the `SELECT` statement and in the `GROUP BY`.